# PHP File Get Contents & String Encoding

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

Retrieved the contents of a css file: (http://gizmodo.com/assets/stylesheets/app-ecbc6044c59319aab4c2a1e31380ef56.css)

Detected the encoding with `mb_detect_encoding`... says UTF-8.

Viewed the page in a browser, looks fine (readable), and declares `@charset "UTF-8";`

Tried to output the string, got garbage.
Tried to save it to a file, got garbage.

Tried to convert the encoding to ASCII, ISO-8859-1, and HTML-ENTITIES. No luck.

Any ideas here how to determine why this string is garbage, and how to fix it?

Comment: im with you up to this line *"Tried to output the string in terminal, got garbage"* then i'm not sure what your doing

Comment: how did you retrieve the contents of the fiie? the code your using would probably make this clearer

Comment: tried both `file_get_contents` and `curl` ... tried on both my local comp and remote server, same result, so i know it's not my config

Comment: Hint: UTF-8 equals Latin1 equals ASCII for files containing only ASCII characters. It will never mess up in its entirety because of a charset mismatch. So you can rule out encodings as a problem source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$url = 'http://gizmodo.com/assets/stylesheets/app-ecbc6044c59319aab4c2a1e31380ef56.css';

$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $data;
```

Important line is

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");
```

Answer (score 5):

The `Content-Encoding` of the page you're trying to fetch is `gzip`.  You'll need to [uncompress](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzdecode.php) it before using it.

[image: Notice the Content-Encoding]

I just tried the following and it worked fine:

```
echo gzdecode(file_get_contents($your_url));
```

Comment: Darn, how'd I miss that! Anyway, you answered first, but @GarrettCosco looks like he's getting started here building rep. Wish I could accept both answers!

Comment: His answer is more "correct" whereas mine is more of a hack/demo.  I'd pick his over mine too.